# TOC with monospaced oldstyle numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, oldstylenums

I'm using oldstyle numbers in my thesis and noticed that the pagenumbers in the table of contents are not providing a straight left line. The following image shows this behaviour for the numbers from a section with 11 subsections.

[image]

In the case of the KOMA-Script classes, the numbers of chapters (or sections in `scrartcl`) can be modified by adding the `Numbers=Monospaced` font feature to the `sectionentrypagenumber`. However, this is not supported (as far as I know) for the lower level sectioning.

How can I get monospaced oldstyle numbers in the TOC?

**EDIT**: I used @egreg's solution to get the monospaced numbers and added the line

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}}
```

to typeset all sectioning in monospaced numbers, too.

Unfortunately, @egreg's solution broke the `siunitx` package, which started to use normal text font instead of math font. I solved this problem by adding the following line:

```
\sisetup{math-rm=\symrm}
```

---

```
\documentclass[a5paper,DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Numbers=OldStyle]

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \section{a}
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \section{a}
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \section{a}
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \section{a}
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum
  \subsection{a}
  \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: The edit is about a completely different problem

Comment: @egreg Probably. But this problem (I think this is a bug in fontspec/unicode-math) appears with your solution and I wanted to show a possible workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily reset the main font for the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,DIV=9]{scrartcl}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Numbers=OldStyle]

% the following just for testing
\newfontfamily{\msf}{Latin Modern Roman}[Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}]

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced},
]
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

Numbers should now be not monospaced:

1234567890

{\msf 1234567890}

\section{a}
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\section{a}
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\section{a}
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\section{a}
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum
\subsection{a}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see from the test that the figures in the top line after the table of contents are not monospaced, while they are in the bottom line.

Comment: I like this solution, because it is very short. To fit the monospaced section numbering, I added `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility appeared with KOMA-Script v3.20 with the subpackage `tocbasic`: The font of the toc entries can be modified with the command `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`.

For my `scrbook`, I added the following lines:

```
% Define new font family with roman font and monospaced, oldstyled numbers
\newfontfamily{\msf}{Latin Modern Roman}[Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}]
% switch all headings and pagenumbers in the document
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\msf}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\msf}
% switch entries in toc
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\msf\bfseries,pagenumberformat=\msf\bfseries]{default}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\msf,pagenumberformat=\msf]{default}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\msf,pagenumberformat=\msf]{default}{subsection}
```

I decided to switch the `entryformat`, instead of `entrynumberformat`, to have a consistent style within the document (cf., `\addkomafont{disposition}{...}`). Additionally, `entrynumberformat` inherits from `entryformat`.

Comment: You could even make this font-independent by using `fontspec`’s `\addfontfeature` command: `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat={\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Uppercase,Monospaced}}},pagenumberformat={\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Uppercase,Monospaced}}}]{default}{subsection}`. In that case, it would always use the default font that you set somewhere else, and therefore when changing the main font, you cannot get a different font in the table of contents by accident.